# Lipschitz Continuity of $\sqrt{1 + \|x\|^2_2}$

Tags: continuity, vector-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a vector-valued function given by $f(x) = \sqrt{1 + \|x\|^2_2}$. Show that the gradient of $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, in particular with Lipschitz constant $L = 1$.

I want to show this directly from $\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\|_2 \leq \|x - y\|_2 \; \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. However, the gradient of $f$ is not exactly very clean, and I get lost in the algebra. Is there a simpler way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe a direct computation of the gradient and looking for an upper bound...

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: Haven't solved it from the direct definition of Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Why do you vote for this question as a duplicate? The question you linked was asked after this question here.

Comment: @Jan The order doesn't matter. Considering both questions and their answers, which one is a better representative of the topic? That's all that matters, and I understand if there are different opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to show it for 1.1 - if we look at the Hessian we get:

$\nabla^2f(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x^Tx)^{3/2}} [(1+x^Tx)I - xx^T]$

So the 2-norm of the Hessian is:

$\begin{align} 
||\nabla^2f(x)||_2 &= ||(1+x^Tx)^{-3/2} [(1+x^Tx)I - xx^T]||_2 \\ &\underset{triangle}{\le} (1+x^Tx)^{-3/2} [||(1+x^Tx)I||_2 + ||xx^T||_2]\\ &= \frac{1+2x^Tx}{(1+x^Tx)^{3/2}} 
\end{align}$

Where the inequality is the triangle inequality. This function is bounded by ~ $1.1$.

EDIT:

Here's a solution (that a classmate of mine found):

Notice that $||I +x^Tx I - xx^T||_2 = ||I + ||x||^2_2(I - \frac{1}{||x||^2_2}xx^T) ||_2$

Now, $\frac{1}{||x||^2_2}xx^T$ is an orthogonal projection into $x$. So $I - \frac{1}{||x||^2_2}xx^T$ is the orthogonal projection into the null space, i.e. it's 2-norm is less than or equal to 1.

So now:

$\begin{align} 
||\nabla^2f(x)||_2 &= ||(1+x^Tx)^{-3/2} [I + ||x||^2_2(I - \frac{1}{||x||^2_2}xx^T)]||_2 \\ &\underset{triangle}{\le} (1+x^Tx)^{-3/2} [||I||_2 + ||x||^2_2||I - \frac{1}{||x||^2_2}xx^T||_2] \\ &\le \frac{1+x^T x}{(1+x^Tx)^(3/2)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^Tx}} \le 1
\end{align}$

Comment: I think the triangle inequality is probably too weak here, and hence leads to a bound of 1.1

Comment: @rw435 yeah, got something better? :-)

Comment: @rw435 check the update

Comment: Hi @MaverickMeerkat, can you please elaborate on the last part of your answer? Regarding the projections etc. Is there another explanation, maybe?